# Branch of mathematics that studies groups / rings or rational functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, rational-functions

I'm not really a mathematician, and looking for some literature which could potentially help me in research. Im interested in algebra of rational functions (ratios of polynomials) of finite order.

Specifically, I'm trying to study classes / families of rational functions that could be used as a basis under addition for all rational functions of a certain order.

Which branch of algebra should I turn to? It's very hard to Google this. Does this even exist as a field of study?

If this is in some sense vague or nonsensical, please ask for specific clarifications.

Comment: Algebraic geometry, if I understand the question correctly?

Comment: By basis under addition do you mean $\Bbb Z$-basis? Or $\Bbb C$-basis? Is your ring of scalars $\Bbb C$? If so, then partial fraction decomposition gives us a $\Bbb C$-basis: nonnegative powers of $x$ and all reciprocals $1/(z-a)^e$ for $a\in\Bbb C$, $e\in\Bbb N$. The branches here are roughly a bit of linear algebra, basic abstract algebra and commutative algebra, maybe a dash of number theory.

Comment: What do you mean by "finite order"?

Comment: My guess is that "order" here means the order of the pole at infinity. It then can make sense to talk about functions of order at most d, since it is stable under addition. The trouble is that this space will be infinite dimensional. You have to specify upper bounds on orders of all poles. Riemann-Roch formula is the one responsible for computation of dimension of the linear space of such functions, even though, in the setting of rational functions, this can be done by hand.

Comment: I don't know that I would call this a "field of study." As far as I can tell, it's an exercise in formalizing partial fraction decomposition to do this.